# Metro UI - add margins between buttons aligned to the right

Tags: html, css, metro-ui-css

I am totally new to the Metro UI Framework and I am currently 'struggling' to add a simple margin between 2 buttons.

http://prntscr.com/e8acp3

This is the current code in pace:

http://prntscr.com/e8ajcd

How do I add a simple margin between the 2 buttons on the right?

Comment: Never mind - at the end I have decided to change the HTML structure as shown on the pictures.

http://prntscr.com/e94znq

Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Use the [helper classes](https://metroui.org.ua/helpers.html). You can add a margin and then turn off the margins you don't want:

```
<button class="button secondary place-right margin10 no-margin-right no-margin-top no-margin-bottom">
    Book off
</button>
```

Unfortunately Metro UI doesn't provide specific margin left/right/top/bottom.